# Using firebase auth inside a 3rd party in-app browser?

Tags: firebase, webview, firebase-authentication, line

In one of my use cases for my react web application, my user will open the  application after following a link generated by a chat bot.

In this case, the specific chat application is LINE, and all links parsed by the chat window are opened by default, in LINE's own web browser.

When the user attempts to login, the login process is halted, in what I believe is the intended behavior, as google has said it has depreciated web-app logins from app webviews in 2016.

Is there any way I can detect one of these in-app browsers and prompt the user to re open the web app in their preferred browser?

If not, does anyone know of a workaround I can use?  Would having a secondary, server side authentication route be the best bet?

Comment: You could check the userAgent for some unique identifier for the in-app browser.